# Scala slick deletion query with Akka & Postgres

Tags: scala, akka, slick-2.0

I'm trying to write a method that simply deletes a row from a database based on an id.

```
class PolicyHolderDAO(database: DatabaseDef) extends CRUDActor[PolicyHolder] {

  private val policyHolders: TableQuery[PolicyHolderTable] = TableQuery[PolicyHolderTable]
  implicit val system: ActorSystem = ActorSystem("Bitcoin-Insurance")
  import system.dispatcher
  implicit val timeout: Timeout = Timeout(5.seconds)
  private implicit var session = database.createSession

  override def receive = {
    case PolicyHolderDAO.Read(id) => sender ! read(id)
    case PolicyHolderDAO.Create(policyHolder) => sender ! create(policyHolder)
    case PolicyHolderDAO.Delete(policyHolder) => sender ! delete(policyHolder)
  }

  /**
   * @param policyHolder the policy holder to inserted into the database
   * @return id
   */
  override def create(policyHolder: PolicyHolder): Future[PolicyHolder] = {
    future {
      (policyHolders returning policyHolders.map(_.id) into
        ((policyHolder, id) => policyHolder.copy(id = Some(id)))) += policyHolder

    }
  }
  /**
   * @param id the id that corresponds to a policy holder
   * @return a future value of a policy holder if the policy holder exists in the database, else it returns none
   */
  override def read(id: Future[Long]): Future[Option[PolicyHolder]] = {
    id.map(i => policyHolders.filter(p => p.id === i).firstOption)
  }

  /**
   * @param policyHolder the policyHolder to be updated
   * @return policyHolder the policyHolders information now saved in the database
   */
  override def update(policyHolder: Future[PolicyHolder]): Future[Option[PolicyHolder]] = {
    /*  //val policyHolderFromDb = policyHolder.map(p => policyHolders.filter(_.id === p.id.getOrElse(-1)))
    val policyHolderFromDb = for (p <- policyHolder;  q = policyHolders.filter(_.id === p.id) ) yield q.update

    val updatedPolicyHolder: Future[Option[PolicyHolder]] = for (p <- policyHolderFromDb; result = create(p)) yield result
    updatedPolicyHolder*/
    Future(None)
  }
  /**
   * @param policyHolder the policy holder to be deleted from our database
   * @return affectedRows the number of rows effected by this query
   */
  override def delete(policyHolder: Future[PolicyHolder]): Future[Int] = {
    val policyHolderId: Future[Long] = policyHolder.map(p => p.id.getOrElse(-1))
    val affectedRows = for (id <- policyHolderId; q = policyHolders.filter(_.id === id)) yield q
    affectedRows.map(q => q.delete)

  }
}
```

I'm trying to test this with this test case written for Scala test

```
  "A PolicyHolderDAO Actor" must {
    "be able to delete an existing policy holder from our database" in {
      val policyHolder = PolicyHolder(None, "Chris", "Stewart")
      val createdPolicyHolderAny: Future[Any] = policyHolderDAOActor ? PolicyHolderDAO.Create(policyHolder)
      val createdPolicyHolder: Future[PolicyHolder] = createdPolicyHolderAny.mapTo[Future[PolicyHolder]].flatMap(p => p)

      policyHolderDAOActor ! PolicyHolderDAO.Delete(createdPolicyHolder)

      val deletedPolicyHolderAny: Future[Any] = policyHolderDAOActor ? PolicyHolderDAO.Get(createdPolicyHolder.map(_.id))
      val deletedPolicyHolder: Future[Option[PolicyHolder]] = deletedPolicyHolderAny.mapTo[Future[Option[PolicyHolder]]].flatMap(p => p)
      whenReady(deletedPolicyHolder, timeout(10 seconds), interval(5 millis)) { p =>
        val policyHolderExists = p match {
          case Some(a) =>
            println(a)
            true
          case None => false
        }
        policyHolderExists must be(false)
      }
    }
  }
```

However I am failing this test. The reason being that the row is NOT being deleted from our database. I am unsure of why this test if failing. I have a corresponding unit test for this method, which is returning 1 affected row as a result of deletion, which makes sense. Could there possibly be something that I don't understand with Akka/Futures?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is likely a race condition in your test right here:

```
...
policyHolderDAOActor ! PolicyHolderDAO.Delete(createdPolicyHolder)

val deletedPolicyHolderAny: Future[Any] = policyHolderDAOActor ? PolicyHolderDAO.Get(createdPolicyHolder.map(_.id))
...
```

It's very difficult to say since you haven't exposed the `Actor` that's doing this, but based on the fact that your `delete` method above returns `Future[Int]`, it seems like what's happening is:

- `policyHolderDAOActor` is passed a delete message in a tell.
- `policyHolderDAOActor` is then immediately asked to retrieve the same record by id.
- `policyHolderDAOActor` calls the `delete` method, which returns a `Future[Int]`, so the result is likely discarded and `receive` returns immediately.
- `policyHolderDAOActor` is then free to process the next message to get the record by id, but the delete hasn't finished processing yet, so the record is still there.

Introducing a wait between the two lines above will *probably* make the test pass, but if it doesn't, perhaps sharing some of the `Actor` code will be more telling.

If the other messages function similarly, it's also possible that the record hasn't even been created yet when you're trying to delete it. The above bullets would still be correct, just with different methods. To be safe, you should probably block on every asynchronous operation within your test, to make sure things process sequentially.

Comment: Side note: You could also shorten `mapTo[Future[Option[PolicyHolder]]].flatMap(p => p)` to `mapTo[Option[PolicyHolder]]`

Comment: I've added the entire actor into the OP.

Comment: Hmm yeah. That's what I expected, so my answer still stands.

Comment: Can this be tested with a simple Thread.sleep in between those two lines?

Comment: It's worth a try. I'd do it between each future to be sure.

Comment: It appears that your solution worked. Thank you. Also your suggestion to shorten with `mapTo` does not work, I get a class cast exception. The method return type is `Future[PolicyHolder]`, not just `PolicyHolder`

Comment: Odd about the `mapTo` but glad you've found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is with passing Slick session to the right place:

1. delete doesn't have 2nd parameter list containing `(implicit val session: Session)`
2. when actor is ready, the session is probably closed. Therefore, you need to explicitly get a new one.

I'm not sure about the 1), because I'm used to use Slick with Play, which might have slightly different API, but I have some experience with 2):

https://github.com/payola/payola-viz/blob/b5668bcbdefc3bce7e6095d211fa04c2aa697685/src/app/model/services/LDVMServiceImpl.scala#L44

Comment: This did not work, I moved creation of the session inside of the method body to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Just a side remark, why not make `delete` simpler?

```
def delete(policyHolder: Future[PolicyHolder]): Future[Int] = {
   for (p <- policyHolder) yield policyHolders.delete(_.id === p.id)
}
```